# Chaining different API calls in a Vue component including one with a for loop

Tags: javascript, vue.js, promise, vuex, es6-promise

I'm trying to understand how to chain two different API calls including one with a for loop in a '**notes**' Vue component. I have a really basic experience of promises and I'm looking to improve.

I'm making a first API call to get all the notes and pushing them into an array using a Vuex mutation. During that first API call I'm also mapping the different users emails into an Object.

Using this mapped object, I'm making a second API call inside a for loop to get all the users avatars.

Here's what the first API call looks like :

```
getAllNotesAPI(entity) {
  noteService.getNotes(entity)
    .then((response) => {

      if (response.data.length === '0') {
        // Set hasData to false if the response is 0
        this.hasData = false;
      } else {
        // Push data into the note array using a store mutation
        this.setAllNotes(response.data);
      }

      // Mapping all users emails into 'userEmails'
      this.userEmails = [...new Set(response.data.map(x => x.userEmail))];

      // Calling my second API call here to get all the avatars associated with these emails
      for (let i = 0; i < this.userEmails.length; i++) {
        this.getAvatarAPI(this.userEmails[i])
      }
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    })
    .finally(() => {
      this.endLoader('notes');
    });
},
```

**this.getAvatarAPI** is the second API call which looks like this :

```
getAvatarAPI(login) {
  userService.getAvatar(login)
    .then((response) => {

      let newAvatar = {
        userEmail: login,
        picture: response.data.picture
      };
      // Push the response into a userAvatar Object using a store mutation
      this.setUserAvatar(newAvatar);
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log(error)
  })
},
```

I've tried using async / await but couldn't figure out how to bind this inside of an async function (this.getAvatarAPI(this.userEmails)) was undefined, I've tried chaining using multiples then but couldn't figure out how to : get all my notes then all my avatars then end the 'note' loader once both those API calls are done.

If any of you could give me some pointers or the beginning of an answer that would be truly appreciated !

Comment: Inside this call: `this.getAvatarAPI(this.userEmails[i])`, it seems like you are not getting a value for `userEmails[i]` hence the undefined error. Are you sure you are also able to map the getAllNotesAPI emails to the variable via the line: `this.userEmails = [...new Set(response.data.map(x => x.userEmail))];`?

Comment: Thank you for your comment Angelo. I am getting a value for `userEmails[i]` and this `this.userEmails = [...new Set(response.data.map(x => x.userEmail))];` definitely works, I am getting all the avatars I need. The only issue is that I do not know when the for loops ends and has gotten all the avatars..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First whilst not related to your problem, avoid for loop when non necessary:

Do you need the i index?

```
  for (let i = 0; i < this.userEmails.length; i++) {
    this.getAvatarAPI(this.userEmails[i])
  }
```

no. You need the userMail. Then

```
  this.userEmails.forEach(userMail => {
    this.getAvatarAPI(userEmail)
  })
```

Now, to synchronize promises, you need to **return** a promise (let's not talk about async yet)

1. make getAvatarAPI return a promise

```
getAvatarAPI(login) {
  return userService.getAvatar(login).then(blabla) // notice the return here
```

2. retrieve the promises of getAvatar API

```
  let promises = this.userEmails.map(userMail => {
    return getAvatarAPI(userEmail)
  })
```

3. return after all promises have fulfilled

```
  let promises = this.userEmails.map(userMail => {
    return getAvatarAPI(userEmail)
  })
  return Promise.all(promises)
```

---

On a side note with async/await

If you use it you are not forced anymore to write return, you need to write async/await though

The underlying idea stay the same. Specifying the async keywords says that your function will return a promise-like.

e.g

```
  async function p () {
    return 5
  }

  p.then(x => console.log(x)) // does print 5 even though we didn't explicitely write return Promise.resolve(5)
```

Now you have to **ensure** you await the async function when you call it:

```
  getAvatarAPI: async login => {
    return userService.getAvatar(login).then(blabla)
  }

  // DO NOT do it
  this.userEmails.forEach(userMail => {
    return await this.getAvatarAPI(userEmail)
  })
```

In forEach loop above, you will do your getAvatarAPI call in **sequence** because await "stops" iterating as long as getAvatarAPI has not resolved.

The proper way would be

```
  getAllNotesAPI: async entity => {
    try { // notice the necesary try-catch block
      const response = await noteService.getNotes(entity)
      blabla
      let promises = this.userEmails.map(userMail => {
        return this.getA...
      })
      let result = await Promise.all(promises)
      // eventually return result, or simply await Promise... without lefthand-side assignment
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
    console.log(this.end('loader'))
  }
```

Comment: Thank you so much ! "1. Make getAvatarAPI return a promise" is what I was missing, the rest was already implemented but wasn't working correctly due to this. What would you consider the best way to write this ? Promise or async / await ? And on another side note, why should I avoir for loop when non necessary when they seem to be more performant all around than their counterparts ? Thank you again for your kind help :)

Comment: I tend to prefer promises because of homogeneity and being accustomized to it. But I am trying to move on to async/await when possible (because it apparently helps people with nested indentation and stack trace in case of errors). So subjective answer. Regarding for loop, ```forEach```, ```map``` and such, most of them allow chaining (.filter().reduce().map()...), avoid scope issues (like in html events), avoid __introducing indices if not needed__ and regarding perfs are completely negligible against an api call. It is likely you find more valuable content on the web than my 600 chars answer.

Comment: Thank you for all theses valuable infos and for your help once more, I'll look into async/await more thoroughly.